# react-select add all items from group by click on group title

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

```
let options = [
  {
    "label": "Group 1",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Item1", "value": "1|1"
      },
      {
        "label": "Item2", "value": "1|2"
      },
      {
        "label": "Item3", "value": "1|3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Group n",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Item1", "value": "2|1"
      },
      {
        "label": "Item2", "value": "2|2"
      }
    ]
  }
];

 <Select
       onChange={this.onChange}
       closeMenuOnSelect={false}
       isMulti
       menuIsOpen={true}
       options={options}
  />
```

`onChange` is fired only for subitems of Group, in documentation I don't find property to set group title clickable or other options that would accomplish this, any ideas?

I also tried to add value for groups like this

```
[
  {
    "label": "Group 1",
    "value": [
      "1|1",
      "1|2",
      "1|3"
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "item1",
        "value": "1|1"
      },
      {
        "label": "item2",
        "value": "1|2"
      },
      {
        "label": "item3",
        "value": "1|3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But group is not clickable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's how `react-select` works, you can't directly be able to click/select on the group.

However, In order to make the group clickable, provide a `label` and `value` in an object inside `options` array.

**Like this**

```js
let options = [
  {
    label: "---GROUP 1---",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    options: [
      {
        label: "Item1",
        value: "1|1"
       ...
```

This will make the group clickable and selectable.

Working copy of your [code is in the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-sub-items-ufom2?file=/src/App.js)

Another info which might be useful to know is:

You can write custom component for the group. This way you can attach `onClick` or do or other kinds of stuff.

```js
<Select
        components={{GroupHeading: () => <div onClick={() => console.log('i am a group and i am clickable .. yay!')}>My Group Heading</div>}}
        onChange={onChange}
```

**====EDIT: Based on request in the comment:====**

In order to select all group items upon clicking on group label, do the following:

- maintain a state `value` for example
- write a little custom component for the group label and attach an `onClick` which will concatenate the value(state)
- use `value` prop of `react-select` and provide the `value` from state
- write custom `onChange` and update the state i.e. `value` upon item select

I have updated the codesandbox working [copy of code (same link as above)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-sub-items-ufom2?file=/src/App.js)

**Code Snippet:**

```js
const group1Options = [
  {
    label: "Item1",
    value: "1|1"
  },
  {
    label: "Item2",
    value: "1|2"
  },
  {
    label: "Item3",
    value: "1|3"
  }
];

const group2Options = [
  {
    label: "Item1",
    value: "2|1"
  },
  {
    label: "Item2",
    value: "2|2"
  }
];

const createGroup = (groupName, options, setValue) => {
  return {
    label: (() => {
      return (
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            setValue(value =>
              value.concat(options.filter(grpOpt => !value.includes(grpOpt)))
            )
          }
        >
          {groupName}
        </div>
      );
    })(),
    options: options
  };
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  let options = [
    createGroup("---GROUP 1---", group1Options, setValue),
    createGroup("---GROUP 2---", group2Options, setValue)
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Select
        // components={{GroupHeading: () => <div onClick={() => console.log('i am a group and i am clickable .. yay!')}>My Group Heading</div>}}
        onChange={option => {
          console.log(option);
          return setValue(option);
        }}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={true}
        options={options}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but after click on group title I want to add all group items as selected, not group as item

Comment: thanks for letting me know... OK - I have updated the answer as well as the codesandbox(use same link) ... it should work as you expected... cheers :)