# Add group title for search by clicking on it in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select custom group-heading component. The options for group are in below format:

```
options = [
  {
    "label": "A",
    "value": "A",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "1",
        "value": "1",  
        "group": "A"
      },
      {
        "label": "2",
        "value": "2",
        "group": "A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "B",
    "value": "B",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "1",
        "value": "1",  
        "group": "B"
      },
      {
        "label": "2",
        "value": "2",
        "group": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using these options in a component like this:

```js
<Select
    components={{ GroupHeading }}
    dropdownIndicator="true"
    onChange={setValue}
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    isMulti
    menuIsOpen={true}
    options={options}
    value={value}
/>
```

I couldn't find a property in the react-select documentation to enable click for group. It only allows clicking on items under group for selection. Can anyone help regarding group heading click for selection?

Comment: Ddi you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340966/react-select-add-all-items-from-group-by-click-on-group-title

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, yes. I tried attaching onClick function to custom group component but couldn't get it working in my example case. Was having syntax issue. Can you help ?

Comment: Whats the syntax issue you are getting, could you add the codesandbox with your code and share it what you have tried so far, so it will easy to help you out the issue :)